# Operator= not working when deriving from QMatrix4x4

Tags: c++

I am trying to derive a class from QMatrix4x4 to add some functionality

```
class MyMatrix: public QMatrix4x4{};
```

once I do this I get the following error message

```
QMatrix4x4 a, b, c;
MyMatrix   A, B, C;

a=a+b;  //works
A=B+C;  //error: no match for operator=
```

It seems I am loosing functionality that previously existed in the parent class. Or why is the assignment not working any more?

Comment: Could you post operator+ ? Maybe it returns wrong type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your derived class probably does not define its own `operator+()`.  Therefore, `B+C` calls `QMatrix4x4::operator+()`, which returns a `QMatrix4x4`. You cannot assign that to your `MyMatrix A` unless `MyMatrix` provides appropriate constructors/assignment operators.